# play sound if condition is true in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to play sound if the condition is correct but it's not working. I tried putting the sound in button it works. Here's my code

```
import playalert from '../src/alert.wav';

function App() {
  const [play, { stop }] = useSound(playalert);

  //some code
  if (value > 14){
    play();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to return the jsx element and put your condition into funciton something like this

```
 const handleClick = () => {
    if(condition) {
     play();
 
    }
    
  };

  return (
    <Button onClick={handleClick}>
      <span role="img" aria-label="Person with lines near mouth">
        
      </span>
    </Button>
  );
```